# Tensorflow Relu Misunderstanding

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I've recently been doing a Udacity Deep Learning course which is based around `TensorFlow`. I have a simple `MNIST` program which is about 92% accurate:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

My next assignment it to `Turn the logistic regression example with SGD into a 1-hidden layer neural network with rectified linear units nn.relu() and 1024 hidden nodes`

I am having a mental block about this. Currently I have a 784 x 10 Matrix of weights, and a 10 element long bias vector. I don't understand how I connect the resulting 10 element vector from `WX + Bias` to 1024 `Relu`s.

If anyone could explain this to me I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Right now you have something like this

[image]

and you need something like this

[image]

(this diagram is missing ReLU layer which goes after +b1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer, I think now have a grasp on what I need to do. X is a 784 element vector, and the process WX + B must result in a 1024 element vector. I'm not sure mathematically where the extra  240 elements come from, aren't they redundant? I feel like I would understand this more intuitively if the number of hidden nodes was <= 784

Comment: Actually it's common to map low-dimensional inputs to higher dimensional spaces in this way. Suppose you had to build a network that models floor(x)%2==0 . Your input is one dimensional, but you have to map it into higher dimensional space first. TensorFlow playground defaults to 2 input neurons and 4 hidden neurons -- http://playground.tensorflow.org/

Comment: Thanks, I guess this actually makes a lot of sense now that I've got a bit further in the course. You want those redundant nodes so that redundant connections can be formed using dropouts etc.

Comment: The part that confused me, that seems to have also confused the author, is the contextual definition of a relu unit or node. In tensorflow, and in this assignment, a relu node is a relu applied to one feature. So if you place the batch_size x 1024 output of your first layer into the tf.nn.relu( ) op, you are adding 1024 relu nodes to your graph since that relu op will apply a relu to each component of each vector in the batch. All it's asking you to do is feed layer1 into 1 tf.nn.relu op. Simple as that.